# Custom widget for GridLayout kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a layout in a GUI using kivy where I will use the same layout for a label several times thus I created a function in top that I try to load in a grid layout but I can't do this for some reason.

It works when it is outside the gridlayout.

Can someone explain what I do wrong and how to fix it?

```
        <settinglabel@Label>:
           size_hint_x: None
           size_hint_y: None
           width: 200
           height: 30
           font_size: 25

        <quickplay_create_setting>: 
           name: "quickcreate_setting"
           Background: 

           GridLayout: 
              size_hint: None, None 
              size: (5, 30)
              pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.8}   
              cols: 2
              spacing: 30  # Increase the vertical spacing between rows

              settinglabel: 
                 text: 'Some text here'
```

Thanks in advance